FastEndpoints - How to use Data class & Where to write queries
I just started to use FastEndpoints (with this article Building REST APIs In .NET 8 The Easy Way). All classes are clearly described and know how to use it, however class Data is big mistery for me? Firstly, I thought, I'm supposed to write the db queries there, but no.
So I have two questions:

How/when should I use the class Data? Could you show me some examples?

Where should I write the queries? Some articles recommend to write it directly to Endpoint while others advice to make repositories with queries and use these queries. The second approach sounds better for me (clearer code), however IMHO it goes against Vertical sliced architecture principles.


Thanks for advices

i'm not sure what you're talking about as there's no Data class in the FastEndpoints library.

I am using Fastendpoints Feature FileSet which generate also class Data (see https://dev.to/djnitehawk/building-rest-apis-in-net-6-the-easy-way-3h0d)

Data class is just static class that was defined in the project, take a look at some examples from your article's source code:

Source/Features/Author/Login/Data.cs
Source/Features/Author/Articles/GetArticle/Data.cs
Source/Features/Author/Articles/SaveArticle/Data.cs
Source/Features/Author/Signup/Data.cs

So, it is some static utility class providing some useful methods created per each "action" - author login, author signup, articles creation, getting articles. This is not something you must use, this is just the way the author decided to implement some stuff.
Where to write queries? This is quite big question and it greatly depends.
Generally recommended is repository pattern - to abstract away databsae you are using from the calling code and put it behind some repository interface (for loose coupling).
However, most recommended (IMO) approach is to BE CONSISTENT WITH WHAT YOU HAVE ALREADY (if you want to change, do a thorough refactor, but don't branch out in a way you do stuff). As I can see in linked classes, those Data classes are serving as sort of repository - doing all the communication with database (not perfect implementation, I would introduce interface).
So, I would say, stick with static Data classes and write the logic there (if you are working on the project from the article). That will be the cleanest solution.
